# Hikari JDBC Pool Monitoring in SpringBoot app with DataDog

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, spring-transactions, datadog

We recently had a production outage where a 3rd party server was non-responsive. This occurred on a Spring Boot EC2 microservice pointing to a MySQL DB.

While waiting for these REST calls to complete, our service started throwing `SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.` errors.

The thing is, we are pretty careful in avoiding keeping a DB transaction open when making a potentially high-latency REST call. Perhaps not careful enough?

We have DataDog monitoring enabled on this microservice and I am not seeing data that would help us diagnose the problem. **Specifically, I would like some visibility in our MySQL db transactions to see where these are being left open longer than expected so we can refactor accordingly**.

If I look at DD APM for the service, I can see the HTTP request latency stats, and JVM metrics which show the thread count creeping up. But no specific stats about transactions and connections from the pool.

If I look at DD APM for the DB, I can see the latency for queries, updates, etc, but it is all ordinary and nothing about transactions themselves.

Is it possible to configure spring and/or datadog for visualizing transaction time?

Comment: You should already have the datasource metrics, as they should be exposed. Be aware that by default Open Session In view is enabled which opens a JPA `EntityManager` at the start of a request and keeps it open until the end. Also this doesn't have to be an open transaction but a connection not being returned to the pool (which is more likely) so gaining tx insight will probably not help, you need to check your datasource and probably enable idle scanning and leak detection.

Comment: these insights are terrific! Thank you